# Show Sticky Posts in Category Archive

Tags: sticky-post, categories

I'd like to be able to show sticky posts at the top of category pages. I'm using archive.php for my category page.

I'm using the code below to display sticky posts at the top of my category archive page followed by the rest of the posts within that category.

This works fine, until there are no sticky posts to display within the category and then it duplicates the posts list.

```
<?php   
// get the current category
$category = get_the_category();
// get the sticky post in the category, order by title - ascending
query_posts(array( 'post__in' => get_option('sticky_posts'), 'orderby' => 'title', 'post_date' => 'DESC' , 'cat' => ''.$category[0]->cat_ID.'' ));
?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php
if ($cat)
{echo "<h2>Articles in " . get_the_category_by_ID($cat) . "</h2>";}
?>
    <ul id="archive-list">      
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>             
        <li class="sticky"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> <span>Updated on <?php the_modified_date(); ?> at <?php the_modified_time() ?></span></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>   

<?php endif; ?>


<?php   
// get the sticky post in the category, order by title - ascending
query_posts(array( 'post__not_in' => get_option('sticky_posts'), 'orderby' => 'title', 'post_date' => 'DESC' , 'cat' => ''.$category[0]->cat_ID.'' ) );
?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <ul id="archive-list">      
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>             
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> <span>Updated on <?php the_modified_date(); ?> at <?php the_modified_time() ?></span></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>   

<?php if(function_exists('wp_page_numbers')) { wp_page_numbers(); } ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <h1 class="center">Sorry, no articles have been published in the <?php if ($cat) {echo "" . get_the_category_by_ID($cat) . "";} ?> category.</h1>
        <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/searchform.php'); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! 
Thanks.

Comment: ant the pagination?
what is the way to integrate the paginate_links() here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use a conditional statement to wrap the first loop, such as:

```
if( get_option('sticky_posts') ) : //only do the next part if sticky posts
```

add the corresponding `endif;` after the `endif;` of the first loop.

Answer (score 2):

Use `wp_reset_query()` after `query_posts()`. We have [lots of posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=wp_reset_query) on this. ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not exactly sure where wp_reset_query() is supposed to go within my code. I have two instances of query_posts(); which one does it go after, and does it need to go inside its own <?php tags?

Comment: It goes after the loop’s end – `have_posts()` `endif;` – and yes, since it is a PHP function it has to happen inside PHP tags. :)

Comment: Thanks for you help (and patients!) @toscho.  I've added <?php wp_reset_query(); ?> after <?php endif; ?> for each loop, but it doesn't have any effect.